# Is it possible to expand the table view's cell at run time?

Tags: iphone, animation, uitableview

I am developing an iphone application .

In which i want to show some detailing by the means of expansion of that cell (i.e. by the means of touching the cell it should animate and exapnd and show the details) and in that show the details related to selected row.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is:

cell is tapped, do a transform on the cell's view to expand it.  Fade it out while fading in a new fullscreen view that has some similarity but has the extra data you want displayed.  When you are done with that view, shrink it while fading out and fade in the cell view again.

Answer (score 0):

have to update the height of the cell.....

Comment: but with smooth transition how can we do it?